# Removing somepart of a dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe named DF like this

Dataframe DF

[image]

I have the below code

```
def func(row):
    temp=row.asDict()
    temp["concat_val"]="|".join([str(x) for x in row])
    put=Row(**temp)
    return put

DF.show()
row_rdd=DF.rdd.map(func)
concat_df=row_rdd.toDF().show()
```

I am getting a result like this

[image]

However I want an output which will remove id and nm colume values from concat_val column.
The table should look like below

[image]

Please suggest a way to remove id and nm value

Comment: 1: you dont need a function for this as pyspark already has a builtin `concat` and `concat_ws` 2: `df.drop` is used to drop columns you pass as arg, kindly refer the documentation.

Comment: If you don't want to use concat do this,  ```temp["concat_val"]="|".join([str(temp[x]) for x in temp if x not in ('id', 'nm')])```

Comment: Sreeram TP...Thanks I got what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

So here you are trying to concat the column `txt` and `uppertx` and the values should be delimited by "|". You can try below code.

```
# Load required libraries
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"a","foo","qwe"), (2,"b","bar","poi"), (3,"c","mnc","qwe")], ["id", "nm", "txt", "uppertxt"])

# Concat column txt and uppertxt delimited by "|" 

# Approach - 1 : using concat function.
df1 = df.withColumn("concat_val", concat(df["txt"] , lit("|"), df["uppertxt"]))

# Approach - 2 : Using concat_ws function
df1 = df.withColumn("concat_val", concat_ws("|", df["txt"] , df["uppertxt"]))

# Display Output
df1.show()
```

## Output

```
+---+---+---+--------+----------+
| id| nm|txt|uppertxt|concat_val|
+---+---+---+--------+----------+
|  1|  a|foo|     qwe|   foo|qwe|
|  2|  b|bar|     poi|   bar|poi|
|  3|  c|mnc|     qwe|   mnc|qwe|
+---+---+---+--------+----------+
```

You can fnd more info on [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) and [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) in spark docs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was kind of looking a generic function.There are a lot of columns(instead of two like here).I could achieve it by doing a small change temp["concat_val"] = "|".join([str(temp[x]) for x in temp if x not in ('id','nm')]) as suggested by someone above.Thanks for your response